# Having trouble setting array size from another array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have to arrays (strings) and i want the second one to be filled with a special character (i.e '*') depending on the size of the first one.
For example if the first is "TEST"
The second should be "****"

So i have this code :

```
int i;
char arr_1[ ] = "TEST";
char *arr_2 = NULL;

arr_2 = malloc( strlen(arr_1) * sizeof(arr_1) );

if(arr_2 ==  NULL)
{
    printf("\nCouldn't allocate memory !");
    exit(0);
}

for(i = 0; i < strlen (arr_1); i++)
{
    arr_2[ i ] = '*';
}

printf("The new string is : %s ", arr_2);

free(arr_2);
```

The problem is that this is not actually working, when i run it i get "****■@!" (stars and some weird characters at the end).

Help is needed, thanks

Comment: `sizeof(arr_1)` is equal to `5`, so you allocate `4 * 5` bytes for `arr_2`. ***And*** you have to remember that `char` strings in C are really called ***null-terminated** byte strings*. You don't terminate the string in `arr_2`.

Comment: Unable to reproduce the error. See [here](https://onlinegdb.com/HkIg9td8V).

Answer (score 0):

You allocate more memory than required. Since the memory is not initialized, then after the word there is garbage.

Use:

```
malloc(sizeof(arr_1)/sizeof(arr_1[0]));
```

Comment: The array itself could be larger, if it was defined with an explicit size. Just `strlen(arr_1) + 1` would be enough for the size.

Answer (score 0):

As others have commented, the allocation for your string is not long enough. With [`strlen`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strlen.htm) you need to allocate `strlen` + 1.

```
arr_2 = malloc( strlen(arr_1) * sizeof(char) + 1);
```

When you copy your string via the `for` loop you need to `NULL` terminate the string.

```
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < strlen(arr_1); i++) {
    arr_2[i] = '*';
  }
  arr_2[i] = '\0';
```

The above code works because the last thing the `for` loop does is increment and compare `i`. Which means `i` is equal to the length of the string. If you need to limit the scope of `i`, wrap the above code in a `do { ... } while(0);`

When using `malloc` you should always assume the allocated memory is full of radioactive garbage data.

Comment: sizeof(char) is always identical to one. And instead of the loop, just use strcpy().

Comment: @FredK - I suggested switching `sizeof(arr_1)` to `sizeof(char)` because `sizeof(arr_1) == 5` in this case. OP probably wanted  `sizeof(*arr_1)`. If the programmer is counting on `sizeof(arr_1) == 5`, arr_1 can decay into a pointer very easily and then `sizeof(arr_1_prime) == 8`. I thought about recommending `strcpy()` / `strncpy()` but when I tried to implement it, it was way more complicated and didn't seem to have any benefits.